# Visual Studio 2010 F# Library Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#

VS Version 10.0.30128.1 RC1Rel

I have a solution that contains an F# Library and an F# Console application, which references the library (through the referenced projects).  I want to be able to step into the library from the console APP, but it is stepping over instead.

Is this a known issue?  Has anybody had success accomplishing debugging this way in the past?

Thx

Comment: When you try placing a breakpoint into the library code, does Visual Studio show any error (when hovering the breakpoint)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling **Enable Just My Code** under Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General

Comment: will try it in the AM.  I appreciate it - just getting back to .NET after a 4 yr run w/ mgt and java.  Its good to be coding again!